# Re: Linking to multiple places on a single page using a dropdown menu?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

Ok, so I've been researching for some time now, without any luck, a way to to access different areas of a single page from a list of links in a dropdown sub-menu that currently contains five (5) working links that go to different pages.

What I'd like to do is keep the separate links for each piece of content, but combine the information from these pages to a single page and then link those specific areas from the existing dropdown menu / sub-menu links.

Can this be done? I understand about anchor tags and have tried to see how I can use them here but it doesn't appear to be an option since I'm not trying to link from within a page, rather from sub-menus in a dropdown menu?

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated, if this is in fact possible! Thanks...

BTW: not sure if it's going to make a difference, but this site is in WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery and following code

HTML:

```
<select id="_selectPlatform" name="_selectPlatform" onChange=selectPlatformChange();>
    <option value="default">Select</option>
    <option value="Android">Android</option>
    <option value="Blackberry">BlackBerry</option>
    <option value="IOS">IOS</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
```

and script code

```
function selectPlatformChange() {
    var _selectPlatform = $('#_selectPlatform').val();
    if (_selectPlatform == 'Android') {
        window.location.href = 'androidpage.html';
    }
}
```

it will work

Comment: just got home from work but will try sometime tonight - one question: not too familiar with JavaScript in WordPress, any suggestions on where/how to place the code?? Thanks...